# After the training phase, is it better to run neural networks on a GPU or CPU?

Tags: graphics-cards, processor

My understanding is GPUs are more efficient for running neural nets, but someone recently suggested GPUs are only needed for the training phase.

Once trained, it's actually more performant to run them on CPUs.

Is this true?

Comment: I think Super User might be the better arena for questions on Neural Networks.

Comment: Doesn't this qualify as recommending "hardware for a specific task?" @ArtOfCode

Comment: @NZKshatriya ok will try there as well though the reason it was posted here was because of the recommending "hardware for a specific task" criterion.

Comment: It does qualify, but I am not sure if there would be as many here as in SU, that would know the specifics of GPUs and Neural Nets......

Comment: @NZKshatriya ok thanks. so how come the question was marked as off-topic? looked at SU before, but it seems off-topic there?

Comment: I have no idea, other than to say that some of the mods have a rather narrow view of what makes a hardware request.  One of my questions was about hard drive enclosures, the types with built in raid functionality, and that prompted a discussion in meta on if that was in scope or not......eventually was allowed.  @ArtofCode, OP is asking about hardware to fit a specific task, specifically GPUs that are good for Neural Networks, in a pre-purchase aspect.   He is not looking to troubleshoot hardware or software.  I vote to reopen.

Comment: @NZKshatriya thanks! to be clear, the goal is to learn -- not cause controversy. :) if this isn't the right forum, that's perfectly okay. just want to understand the guidelines more clearly for future questions. if the mods decide the q is on-topic, it would be great to learn the community. and to be clear, the question is which hardware is more performant for running neural nets *after the training phase* -- GPU or CPU?

Comment: I think this question can be broken into two, and have the respective sections be asked both here and in SU, in the right order.  Ask about whether or not GPUs or CPUs are the better choice for each stage in SU.  Once that is accomplished, come back here for hardware recommendations.